# could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows" python34 PyQt4 pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x

after use pyinstaller app didnt work and get this  "" This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows".

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. ""

Answer (score 0):

finally Got it !!
after hours of searching i found solution round about " plugins platforms "
so i just take a copy from main pyqt4 file plugin platform and pasted in qt4_plugins where pyinstaller put my app
and my app work fine >> i hope that could help , thanks ---
note: my app built with python 3.4 - pyqt4 - qt